# How to change the cursor type to be like Excel grid cursor?

Tags: delphi

How i can change the cursor type in a `TStringGrid` to be like **Excel** grid cursor

The Excel cursor is not a cursor type in delphi or system32.

I used the code in [swat example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/VCL.Swat_Sample) where the cursor is in `extrares.res`

```
Screen.Cursors[crMaletUp] := LoadCursor(HInstance, 'Malet');
Screen.Cursors[crMaletDown] := LoadCursor(HInstance, 'MaletDown');
Screen.Cursor := TCursor(crMaletUp);
```

in othe hand i use other code but which put in help but it does't work

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  bmpMask := TBitmap.Create;
  bmpColor := TBitmap.Create;

  bmpMask.LoadFromFile('SquareMask.bmp');
  bmpColor.LoadFromFile('Square.bmp');

  with iconInfo do
  begin
    fIcon := false;
    xHotspot := 15;
    yHotspot := 15;
    hbmMask := bmpMask.Handle;
    hbmColor := bmpColor.Handle;
  end;

  Screen.Cursors[crMyCursor] := CreateIconIndirect(iconInfo);

  Screen.Cursor := crMyCursor;

  bmpMask.Free;
  bmpColor.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Can you link an image of the cursor?

Comment: Make a screenshot of the cursor and post the image here so we can see what kind of a cursor you want.

Comment: How about some error checking? What does `CreateIconIndirect` return?

Comment: the cursor is like cross +

Comment: Anyway, it's much easier to get a cursor file, compile it to a resource, and link that.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan: use a resource editor to create an Icon resource in a .res file, and use that in your code.

Comment: actually there IS a standard cross cursor in Microsoft Windows, for every application: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Controls.TCursor

Comment: how to get get a cursor file where it is in

Comment: I've voted to close this. It's not a real question. The question contains *two* examples of how to assign custom cursors. Furthermore, as Arioch points out, a custom cursor isn't even necessary since Delphi already supports exactly the cursor being requested here. What more is there to ask? At best, this is a question asking how to debug, which is far too broad a question to be handled at Stack Overflow.

Comment: As @RobKennedy points out, Delphi *has* a standard `TCursor` for exactly this shape. In Delphi 2007, at least, you can click on the `TForm.Cursor` property and get a visual look at the cursor when selecting the type, and the documentation (as far back as Delphi 7, the oldest I have installed now) shows sample images in the `TCursor` topic, so there's no excuse for you not finding it. Voting to close for the same reason.

Comment: @Rob None of the built in cursors look quite like the Excel cross cursor.

Comment: @RobKennedy You're confusing Hikmat's (failed) attempts at solving his own problem for an **actual** answer. It shows that he *tried*, but both approaches failed him. That is when we provide an *actual* answer. Don't confuse attempts at answers, with answers.

Comment: @Ian, the question asks how to change the cursor. Those *are* the ways to change the cursor. There is no problem *presented in the question* that isn't addressed by those two techniques. Thus, this is not a real question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i guess i'll answer the question, since nobody else will.

i have a function that fixes some of Delphi's built-in cursors (to use the *standard* Windows cursors). But i also use it to add some new custom cursors. i'll trim down my function to only **add** two new cursors:

- `crColorPicker`: [image] *(a color picker cursor)*
- `crExcelCross`: [image] *(an Excel cross cursor)*

First i needed to create an `ExcelCross.cur` in Visual Studio:

[image]

Now create a new resource script file, **wumpa.rc**, where i will specify my two cursor files:

**wumpa.rc**

```
ColorPicker    CURSOR   "ColorPicker.cur"
ExcelCross     CURSOR   "ExcelCross.cur"
```

And add that `wumpa.rc` file to my project using **Project** -> **Add to project**.

Now i declare two global constants to represent my new cursors. Like `crHourGlass`, or `crNo`, we will now have `crColorPicker` and `crExcelCross`:

```
const   
   {Cursor Constants}
   crColorPicker =  1003;
   crExcelCross = 1004;
```

Now we have to load those two `CURSOR` resources at runtime:

```
procedure LoadNewCursors;
var
    i: Integer;
    cursorHandle: HCURSOR;
begin
    //Load ColorPicker cursor
    cursorHandle := LoadCursor(hInstance, 'ColorPicker');
    if CursorHandle <> 0 then
        Screen.Cursors[crColorPicker] := cursorHandle
    else
        Screen.Cursors[crColorPicker] := Screen.Cursors[crNone];

    //Load Excel Cross cursor
    cursorHandle := LoadCursor(hInstance, 'ExcelCross');
    if CursorHandle <> 0 then
        Screen.Cursors[crExcelCross] := cursorHandle
    else
        Screen.Cursors[crExcelCross] := Screen.Cursors[crNone];
end;

initialization
    LoadNewCursors;
```

With that working, i can set my **StringGrid** to use `crExcelCross`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    StringGrid1.Cursor := crExcelCross;
end;
```

And *ba-zinga*, you have an Excel cross cursor:

[image]

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.